# Cannot access tomcat from AWS cloud

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an Amazon free tier instance in AWS EC2. Its an unix instance where i have installed tomcat deployed my war file there. The n i started my server and tried to access it like **http://aaa.bb.cc.dd:8080/my_app** but my web browser returns this msg

```
**Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to aaa.bb.cc.dd:8080**
```

In my server.xml i have modified like this

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="aaa.bb.cc.dd">
          <Host name="aaa.bb.cc.dd"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

what may be the issue in here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging into your instance and making sure that it is listening on localhost. If it is, a very common issue is not enabling port 8080 on your security group, you can find a link to your security group in you instance description tab and follow that to add a rule allowing port 8080.

Comment: Thanks.  I have added the inbound rule for http. But it automatically takes the port 80. Though i set that rule. Still am not able to access. Any ideas?

Comment: I have modified the inbound rules for the port and now am able to access it.. thanks @Julio Faerman